# How do I remove configuration files for a program that's not installed?

Tags: debian, package-management, aptitude

I'm basically looking for an `apt-get purge` for programs that are already uninstalled.

(I'm running Debian squeeze and using `aptitude` for package management.)

Answer (score 4):

The following sequence will list your deinstalled packages,

```
dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall
```

You can switch that to `purge` with a `sed` replace.
Is that what you are looking for?

You can run that `purge` list through `dpkg --set-selections` and
run `dpkg --purge --pending` on the marked packages...

Or, something like,

```
for pkg in $(dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | awk '{print $1}'); 
do 
  dpkg -L $pkg; 
done
```

will list the files hanging around from these `deinstall`'ed packages.

Comment: Actally, it seems like if you `apt-get remove` a package that has configuration files, you can later remove them just with `apt-get purge $package`. IIRC, I'd tried that and it didn't work, through, giving me a package-not-installed error…

Comment: Hmm. Did you try `dpkg -L` on these packages? Does it show any files?

Comment: Just tested this again. Did a `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall`, then picked one of the packages from that output. `dpkg -L $package` listed several configuration files the package had created. `apt-get remove $package` returned a not-installed-so-not-removed warning, but `apt-get purge $package` asked if I wanted to continue with removing the package, then did so. After that, it did not show up in `dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall`.

Comment: Hmm, that is not my experience. When I run purge, it says "Package $package is not installed, so not removed", and then it still shows up in the list.

Answer (score 3):

In aptitude you filter just the packages that are deinstalled but still have configuration files remaining (which are in state 'c').

1. press <kbd>L</kbd>
2. filter for `~c`
3. purge all listed packages by pressing <kbd>_</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

I found [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35143/18887) the simplest.

---

The following should do what you want:

```
aptitude purge \~c
```

This purges all packages with the `c` (package removed, configuration files still present) state flag. Flag documentation is here.